# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jScrollPane is not a function

Tags: html, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" ></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>




#scroll-pane {
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 1%;
                        left: 67.3%;
                        width: 350px; 
                        height: 56%; 
                        overflow: auto; 
                        background-color: red;
                    }  





     <form id="upload" method="post" action="../scripts/dragdrop/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div id="drop">
                    Drop Here Music

                    <a>Browse</a>
                    <input type="hidden" value="BN" id="BNforUpload" name="BN"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="AN" id="ANforUpload" name="AN"/>
                    <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

                <ul id="scroll-pane">
                    <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
                </ul>

            </form>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    jQuery('#scroll-pane').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
                });
            </script>



Пытаюсь поставить jScrollPane 2 

Выдаёт Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jScrollPane is not a function

В <ul> будут добавляться динамически элементы списка

В работоспособности плагина уверен, проверял отдельно

Не могу понять в чём дело, помогите пожалуйста
```

Comment: Подключите последнюю версию библиотеки jQuery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: не помогло
скрол остаётся стандартным
ошибка та же

Comment: какие ошибки вы видите в консоли браузера?